# Reaction event discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a starboard code with my bot, and everything else is working good. But I'm trying to make it to where the bot ignores reactions from the author of the actual message.

This is my current code:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction_orig, message, user) => {
  if (message.author.id === reaction_orig.users.id) return

  manageBoard(reaction_orig)
})
```

It returns the following error:

```
if (message.author.id === reaction_orig.users.id) return;
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) takes two parameters; the message reaction as the first one, and the user that applied the emoji as the second one. When you write `reaction_orig, message, user`, `reaction_orig` is the reaction (which is correct), but `message` is the user who reacted as it's the second parameter. The `user` variable will be `undefined`.

Another issue is that `reaction_orig.users` returns a [ReactionUserManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/ReactionUserManager) that doesn't have an `id` property. Luckily, the `user` is already passed down to your callback so you can use its ID.

Also, `reaction_orig` has a `message` property, the original message that this reaction refers to so you can get its authors' ID from it.

You can change your code to this to work:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction_orig, user) => {
  if (reaction_orig.message.author.id === user.id) {
    // the reaction is coming from the same user who posted the message
    return;
  }

  manageBoard(reaction_orig);
});
```

However, the code above only works on cached messages, ones posted after the bot is connected. Reacting on older messages won't fire the `messageReactionAdd` event. If you also want to listen to reactions on old messages you need to enable partial structures for `MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL` and `REACTION` when instantiating your client, like this:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
});
```

You can check if the message is cached by e.g. checking if its `author` property is not `null`. If it's `null`, you can [fetch the message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch). Now, you have both the message author and the user who reacted, so you can compare their IDs:

```js
// make sure it's an async function
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction_orig, user) => {
  // fetch the message if it's not cached
  const message = !reaction_orig.message.author
    ? await reaction_orig.message.fetch()
    : reaction_orig.message;

  if (message.author.id === user.id) {
    // the reaction is coming from the same user who posted the message
    return;
  }
  
  // the reaction is coming from a different user
  manageBoard(reaction_orig);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (!reaction.message.author.id === user.id){
        //Do whatever you like with it
        console.log(reaction.name)
    }
});
```

Note: The message must be cached. For that you'll need to do this

```js
Client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID").messages.fetch("MessageID");
```

I'm guessing you're using discord.js v12